# Single Table Inheritance - discriminator map

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am needing to make a formula to DiscriminatorMap in my class, because I have a lot of class, and I can't discrimine each one.

The discr can be the name of the class.

it's possible? (with annotation, xml or other)

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"MidUpperArmCircumference" = MidUpperArmCircumference", "KneeHeight" = "KneeHeight"})
*/
```

thanks.

Comment: Don't think there's a way to automatically map it, sorry

Comment: =/ so I Will discriminate all. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look this link maybe it'll help you.

https://medium.com/@jasperkuperus/defining-discriminator-maps-at-child-level-in-doctrine-2-1cd2ded95ffb

Comment: Link is available [here](https://medium.com/@jasperkuperus/defining-discriminator-maps-at-child-level-in-doctrine-2-1cd2ded95ffb)

Answer (score 2):

I simply left out the `DiscriminatorMap` annotation and Doctrine automatically used the chield's class name as a discriminator:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 */
abstract class AbstractContent
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Page extends AbstractContent
{
}
```

Now when I create a new `Page()` Doctrine creates an `AbstractContent`and a `Page` with an FK to the `AbstractContent` and sets the `AbstractContent`'s `type` attribute to `page`.

This perfect as it let's you generate as many subclasses as you like even in other Bundles without your Superclass (in my case `AbstractContent`) needing to know about them.

But keep in mind that so far this isn't officially documented. Tested with Doctrine ORM 2.3.

Comment: this does not behave as described. it also generates duplicate fields on the subclass tables

Comment: @CarrieKendall Can you provide me with your classes because this still works perfectly fine in our projects.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. Doctrine supports single table inheritance pretty well.
The below example is from [official docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
 */
class Person
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Employee extends Person
{
    // ...
}
```

Read more about it [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)